# ER Diagram and relational database - prevent different entites from "taking place" at the same time?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I need to make an ER Diagram (and map it to a relational database model) for the following segment of reality:

- a single lecture can take place in multiple rooms (in general)
- in a single room, multiple lectures can take place
- but at a particular point in time, only one lecture can take place in a room
- it takes place at some day and has a begin and end time *(e.g. Monday 2pm-4pm)*

I am not sure how to construct my ER-Diagram (and my relational database model) in such manner, that it is impossible for lectures to overlap (e.g. Lecture 1 takes place on Monday 2pm-4pm in Room 1. Lecture 2 takes place on Monday 2:30pm-5pm, also in Room 1.)

Setting the day or the begin/endtime as a key attribute doesn't really help (in fact, it brings up a lot of limitations). The only thing that comes to my mind is to define some "minimum" how long a lecture  may last (e.g. 1 hour, so if I say that Lectue 1 beings at 2pm in Room 1, that automatically implies that Room 1 is taken from 2pm to 3pm).

Here is my attempt:
[image: My attempt]

Any ideas? Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an academic exercise on how to use the relational model to impose a constraint on how many lectures can be assigned to a particular room at a particular time then you want to have a table of rooms with a child table of dates and times of day (say in one hour increments, if this is your scenario).  This child table would have an optional foreign key to your course table, indicating that the course is held in that place at that time.  Something like this:

`CLASSROOM -|----IO< TIMESLOT >O-----O|- COURSE`

Because the place/time record points to the (zero or) one course that takes place then and there, it is not possible for lectures to conflict with each other.

**However, this is a bad design for practical purposes.**

Instead, date/time ranges should be recorded as start and end points, and overlaps can be found using SELECT queries as demonstrated in my answers to these two questions: [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280333/how-to-manage-rooms-availability-based-on-days-or-months-occupation/10280605#10280605) [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253921/how-can-i-store-resource-available-by-date-year-month-day-our-in-database/17256510#17256510)

Comment: Well explained and thank you! I will consider all of this while making the database. Btw. I have edited my original question by posting a screenshot of the corresponding ER-diagram. I assume it is correct, as I cannot express more than that due to the ER-diagram not being semantically strong enough.

Comment: @Infecto Your ERD looks good.  I'd add that in a physical model the simplest implementation would be to combine day (date) with time for both the start and end points.  This would vastly simplify your SQL queries.